# Why can't I get ssl to work with tomcat and centos 7

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, centos7

I can't seem to figure out why I can't get my ssl on tomcat in centos 7 to work I have created the ip tables to match the incoming request

[image: IpTables for centos 7]

I have also set up the server.xml file

[image: server.xml]

with that being said I have followed all of the text book standards and even standards in other tutorials. I have done this on my desktop to test how it may work or may not work, I had no issues with it on my desktop whatsoever.

After building the keystore file like so:

```
keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore
```

and as I have already shown with the server xml image set the server up to look at this file.

After doing all of the necessary steps before wasting time and downloading the certificates and importing them I decided to run a test against the server. I plugged the ip address:8443 into the url bar of the browser like so:

[image: url path to server with ssl]

and this is what I am getting in return...

[image: connection reset]

Anyone have any ideas of what is going on here? As I said I did all of the same things when trying this on my desktop and got it to work fine there but no luck here.

EDIT:::

Okay so I got the SSL to work, I am still not sure what it was, I think it just took some time for my iptables to pick up. However now I am having an issue when setting the certificates, I set the certificates to the keystore file but afterwards the site practically dies. My question here is that when do I derive the private key for the node balancer that I am using. I imagine that this would have to be done after the certificates are set to the keystore correct?

Comment: Is Tomcat on your CentOS box fronted by Apache Web server (httpd) or another Web server?

Comment: @davidlevesque Nope just tomcat

Comment: no helpful output in catalina.log? Are the permissions for the keystore file correct set?

Comment: @AydinK, no errors in the catalina.log, permissions are set correctly. I will be updating the question shortly. I got the ssl to work now I am having an issue with setting certificates to the keystore.